# Running UI thread indefinitely

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, swingworker

I am writing a piece of code using Java Swing. Basically what it does is that it processes some lengthy task. While the task is running, I want to have a waiting pop-up window with a GIF image in it.

My question is that

```
        final InfoDialog infoDialog = new InfoDialog("Parsing file: " + fileToBeUploaded.getName());

        final File finalFileToBeUploaded = fileToBeUploaded;

        class FileParsingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {            
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                String text = fileParsers.parseFile(finalFileToBeUploaded);
                publish(text);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                infoDialog.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

        infoDialog.setVisible(true);
        FileParsingWorker fileParsingWorker = new FileParsingWorker();
        fileParsingWorker.execute();
```

The InfoDialog is the small UI pop-up window with a GIF animation in it. Basically, I put the lengthy task in the worker but the UI's setVisibles in two places. I am thinking if there is any ways I can run the InfoDialog UI in a thread so that I can reuse that bit of code?

The problem I have is that I want to try to run the InfoDialog indefinitely until I deliberately stop it. If I put setVisible(true) in a thread, that thread immediately terminates and my UI won't be updated.

Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: Where do you set dialog to visible?

Answer (score 3):

Please have a read on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) specifically [The Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). This is the thread on which all Swing components should be created and manipulated. i.e:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable () {
    @Override
    public void run() { 
        final InfoDialog infoDialog = new InfoDialog("Parsing file: " + fileToBeUploaded.getName());

        final File finalFileToBeUploaded = fileToBeUploaded;

        ...

        infoDialog.setVisible(true);
        FileParsingWorker fileParsingWorker = new FileParsingWorker();
        fileParsingWorker.execute();
    }
});
```

Also I think another problem is you set the `dialog` back to invisible in overriden `process(List<String> chunks)` of the Swing worker, thus as the first chunk is read the `dialog` will be closed. I think Swing Workers [`done()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done%28%29) method might be more what you want, and its executed on EDT:

```
class FileParsingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {            
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        String text = fileParsers.parseFile(finalFileToBeUploaded);
        publish(text);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
      //each chunk will get processed here
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {//when Swing worker is finished this method is called
        infoDialog.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - just nitpicking: as long as publish is called once only, it doesn't matter much :-)